# How to replace a line in a .txt file with attributes from an object

Tags: python, file, class, replace, txt

I'm a beginner in programming Python

So basically I'm having trouble finding a way to make the function "modif_customer" work

I need the user to be able to insert a replacement name and address after searching for the customer through an ID that has been given beforehand (and that has to stay the same)
So basically, 2 values have to be replaceable through user input in the list_customers.txt, and those are the name of the customer, and their address.

list_customers.txt is structured in a name, address, ID number pattern like such:

**list_customers.txt:**

William,3rd Street,1

Jeanne,14th Boulevard,2

Johny,29th Street,3

```
class Customer:
  number_of_customers = 0 
  def __init__(self, name, address, customerID = 0):
    self.name = name
    self.address = address
    Customer.number_of_customers += 1
    self.customerID = Customer.number_of_customers

#############################################

fileObj1 = open("list_customers.txt", "r")
list_customers = fileObj1.readlines()
fileObj1.close()

for ind in range(0, len(list_customers)):
  if list_customers[ind][-1] == '\n':
    list_customers[ind] = list_customers[ind][0:-1]
  list_customers[ind] = list_customers[ind].split(',')
  list_customers[ind] = Customer(list_customers[ind][0], list_customers[ind][1], list_customers[ind][2])


###############################################


def modif_customer(list, name, address):
  findcustomerID = input("\nPlease enter the ID of the customer to be modified: ")
  new_name = input("Enter the replacement name of the customer: ")
  new_address = input("Enter the new address of the customer")

  for ind in range(0, len(list_customers)):
    if str(list_customers[ind].customerID) == str(findcustomerID):
      fileObj2 = open("list_customers.txt", "w")
      for object in list_meals:
        new_line = object.name == new_name + ',' + object.address == new_address + ',' + object.mealID +'\n'
        fileObj2.write(new_line)
      fileObj2.close()

modif_customer()
```

Comment: Although this doesn't offer any immediate solution to your problem specifically, perhaps consider using sqlite database to store your data instead of a txt file - very easy to learn and also much easier to manipulate data in shorter lines of code :)

Comment: @ChrisT-Pot: You're suggestion is right for an advanced programmer, but I think a beginner should first learn how to work with pure text files before working with database libs.

Comment: You've described what you expect your function to do but please add what it actually does: how does the broken result look like or is there an error message or what else?

Answer (score 0):

Some notes on what you were trying to do:

1. When opening/closing files, context managers (with statements) are nice to use.
2. When looping over a list, you don't have to iterate over the range and index it.  You should just loop over the list and get the items.  If you need the index, then use enumerate().
3. You can use `strip` to remove the ending '\n' on a string.
4. Try not to use builtin types (like `list`) as parameters as that can cause problems if you go to use it, and also messes with your syntax highlighter.

You seemed to ignore the CID from the input file in favor of the counter in `Customer`. I left this as is, but it seemed strange that the ID from the file wouldn't be respected.  I also assumed that all input lines have the three fields separated by a comma, as you said it was structured.

Lastly, I'm not sure where list_meals came from in your code.  So I tried to simply match what your description said you were trying to do.

```
class Customer:
  number_of_customers = 0 
  def __init__(self, name, address, customerID = 0):
    # Why does this completely ignore customerID?
    self.name = name
    self.address = address
    Customer.number_of_customers += 1
    self.customerID = Customer.number_of_customers

  def __str__(self):
      '''
      Defines how the customer is represented as a string.  
      Since you want it as a CSV, you could simply do that here.
      If this object is used for other things and in different ways
      then you may want a dedicated function for getting the csv
      representation
      '''
      return ','.join([self.name, self.address, str(self.customerID)])

#############################################

# Takes care of closing for you
with open("list_customers.txt", "r") as stream:
    lines = stream.readlines()

def get_customer(line):
    '''Converts a line of CSV into a Customer'''
    line = line.strip()
    name, address, cid = line.split(',')
    return Customer(name,address, cid)

# Runs the get_customer function on every line in lines.
# Could also do:
#    customers = list(map(get_customer, lines))
# But I think most people prefer the list comprehensions
customers = [get_customer(line) for line in lines]
# Or a 1-liner
# customers = list(map(lambda line: Customer(*line.strip().split(','))))    
###############################################


def modif_customer(customers):
    findcustomerID = input("\nPlease enter the ID of the customer to be modified: ")
    new_name = input("Enter the replacement name of the customer: ")
    new_address = input("Enter the new address of the customer: ")

    # Find the matching customer and change it's data
    for customer in customers:
        if customer.customerID == int(findcustomerID):
            customer.name = new_name
            customer.address = new_address
            break
    
    # Write all of the customers to the file.  Don't need to 
    # Could collapse this into a single loop above by opening the
    # the file and then through every loop write the str(customer)
    # to the file.  This just makes the printing of the \n nice and easy.
    with open('list_customers.txt', 'w') as stream:
        stream.write('\n'.join(map(str, customers)))


modif_customer(customers)
```

Comment: Thanks you, it works perfectly!

I'll remember the tips too

Still making tons of mistakes, barely started three weeks ago.

Comment: Made some updates to better comment the code, hopefully to make it more teachable than copy/paste.